# Python: How do I install django-extensions into a virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I've created a virtualenv with -no-sitepackages. I'd like to install django-extensions into this virtualenv. The thing is when I run:

```
python setyp.py install
```

from within the virtualenv, it creates and writes to

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django_extensions-0.4.1.egg-info.
```

What's the correct way to get django-extensions into a virtualenv?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `pip install -E your_virtualenv_here django-extensions`, then just activate and you're set.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have activated your virtualenv? Usually you use `source <virtualenv_path>/bin/activate`. Check for a $VIRTUAL_ENV environment variable as well.

Comment: Yes, I have activated the virtualenv. and the VIRTUAL_ENV env variable is set correctly.